# Convert jQuery map function to arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to convert following working function into an arrow function but I'm failing. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

This is my starting situation:

```
let abc = Math.max.apply( null, $( "#wrapper .item" ).map( function () {
    return parseInt( $( this ).prop( "id" ).match( /\d+/g ), 10 );
} ) );
```

And this is what I've tried. Maybe I misunderstood something?:

```
let abc = Math.max.apply( null, $( "#wrapper .item" ).map( item => parseInt( item.prop( "id" ).match( /\d+/g ), 10 ) ) );
```

The given error is:

> issue.prop is not a function.

So I've tried a different one:

```
let abc = Math.max.apply( null, jQuery( "#wrapper .item" ).map( issue => parseInt( jQuery(issue).prop( "id" ).match( /\d+/g ), 10 ) ) );
```

Bit this gives me this error:

> Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

What I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function passes `Integer` index and `Element` domElement to the callback respectively.

```js
$(function() {
    let abc = Math.max.apply(null, $('#wrapper .item').map( (index, item) => parseInt( $(item).prop('id').match( /\d+/g ), 10 ) ) );

    console.log(abc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="item1" class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div id="item2" class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div id="item3" class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery `.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) is not [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). jQuery passes first the `index` and then the `element`  to the callback while [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) passes first the `element` then the `index`.

So do:

```js
let abc = Math.max.apply( null, $("#wrapper .item")
  .map((idx, item) => parseInt($(item).prop('id').match( /\d+/g ), 10)))
;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item" id="item1"></div>
  <div class="item" id="item2"></div>
</div>
```

---

(also you replaced `$(item).prop` by `item.prop` which will not work)

Comment: If you have more than one argument for an arrow function, you need to wrap them in parentheses.

Comment: Also the order of your arrow function arguments doesn't match the text description you posted.

Comment: Still getting the error item.prop is not a function :/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the looks of it, it seems that you are trying to find the largest `id` value (assuming they are all numeric) given a specific selector. I'll provide examples (and a breakdown of what's happening) for both native Javascript as well as jQuery.

### Native Javascript Approach (will work with jQuery as well)

```js
// Get your items
let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper .item')];

// Parse your ids
let ids = items.map(i => parseInt(i.id.match(/\d+/g), 10));

// Get the max
let max = Math.max.apply(null, ids);

// Output it
console.log(max);
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='item-123' class='item'>123</div>
  <div id='item-456' class='item'>456</div>
  <div id='item-789' class='item'>789</div>
  <div id='item-101112' class='item'>101112</div>
  <div id='item-131415' class='item'>131415</div>
</div>
```

Then you can just put it all together in a single, albeit bit, statement if you prefer:

```js
let max = Math.max.apply(null, [...document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper .item')].map(i => parseInt(i.id.match(/\d+/g), 10)));

console.log(max);
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='item-123' class='item'>123</div>
  <div id='item-456' class='item'>456</div>
  <div id='item-789' class='item'>789</div>
  <div id='item-101112' class='item'>101112</div>
  <div id='item-131415' class='item'>131415</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery Specific Approach

If you are using jQuery specifically and want to take advantage of it as much as possible, then you'll just need to make a few changes:

```js
let max = Math.max.apply(null, [...$('#wrapper .item')].map(i => parseInt($(i).prop('id').match(/\d+/g), 10)));

console.log(max);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='wrapper'>
  <div id='item-123' class='item'>123</div>
  <div id='item-456' class='item'>456</div>
  <div id='item-789' class='item'>789</div>
  <div id='item-101112' class='item'>101112</div>
  <div id='item-131415' class='item'>131415</div>
</div>
```

The *only* differences being the syntaxes for:

- **Selection** - using jQuery's `$(selector)` vs Javascript's `querySelector(selector)`
- **Property Access** - using jQuery's `.prop(id)` vs Javascript's `id` property

Answer (score 0):

Suggested changes:

- Instead of jQuery's `$( )` selector you can use `document.querySelectorAll`
- Instead of jQuery's `.map()` you can use `Array.from` with its callback argument
- Don't use `g` on the `.match` regular expression, as you want only one match (if ever there would be multiple matches, using `g` would give `NaN`)
- You can use the unary `+` on the result instead of `parseInt(***, 10)`.
- You can access the `id` property with simple `.id` syntax.
- Instead of `apply` you can use the spread syntax.

```js
let abc = Math.max(...Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('#wrapper .item'), item => +item.id.match(/\d+/)
));
console.log(abc);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="id439" class="item"></div>
    <div id="id20"  class="item"></div>
    <div id="id392" class="item"></div>
</div>
```